# Energy consumption off CNN models

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I want to calculate/estimate the energy consumption for the different convolutional neural networks. Is there any possibility to measure the energy consumed by AlexNet for example with a tool or with Keras or something else?

Answer (score 2):

The energy usage will vary depending on the machine, but as long as all of your results are from the same setup there's a comparatively low-tech, simple solution: Hook up your computer to an electricity meter and take some measurements with the computer "at rest", to get a baseline of its energy consumption. Then, run several trials with each model you're testing, and adjust the readings by the baseline to get the net difference in energy consumption when the model is running.